# How to generate CSV with | separated values using Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, csv, processing, procedure, bulk

I am trying this procedure. I want to generate csv using oracle procedure table contains more than 500k records. Database = Oracle 12c

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        test_date;

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE genratedata (
        to_date   NVARCHAR2,
        curr      SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) AS
    BEGIN
        OPEN curr FOR SELECT
                          product_name   AS "PRODUCT",
                          expiry_date    AS "END DATE"
                      FROM
                          test_date
                      WHERE
                          expiry_date <= to_date;

    END;
```

Comment: Why do you want to generate csv "using oracle procedure"? Is creating the csv **in a procedure** part of the requirement? If it isn't, don't present it like that. Tell us that the requirement is to create the csv (that is, by any means). Then you can tell us that your current thought is to do it in a procedure. Hint: What you are asking can very likely (almost surely) be done much more efficiently in a standard SQL query - even if you then still need some more work to take the output and save it in a .csv file.

Comment: Yes, It is requirement to generate csv daily with bulk data in system.

Comment: I didn't ask if it is requirement to generate csv. I asked if the requirement includes HOW to generate it - namely, if you are required to do it in a procedure, not in any other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL*Plus (as of 12.2) feature to do this:

```
SQL> select * from t;

     X Y          Z
---------- ---------- --------------------
     1 A          a
   100 A Z        a z

SQL> set markup csv on delimiter | quote off;
SQL> set heading off 
SQL> select * from t;
1|A|a
100|A Z|a z

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the SQL*Plus to fulfill your task as given in another answer, But if there is a limitation of using the procedure then you must `concat` each column as follows:

```
...
...
BEGIN
    OPEN CURR FOR SELECT '"'
                         || PRODUCT_NAME
                         || '"|"'
                         || EXPIRY_DATE
                         || '"|"'
                         || OTHER_COLUMNS
                         || '"' AS CSV_LINES
                    FROM TEST_DATE
                   WHERE EXPIRY_DATE <= TO_DATE;

END;
```

**Note**: It is better practise to use the double quotes to wrap each the column values. We are trying to generate the csv with (pipe) delimiter, If there is a pipe in actual data then CSV will be corrupted if double quotes are not present. That is why double quotes are used.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your *note*, Tejash. This is Oracle. Why on Earth would you suggest anyone to use double quotes with column names? From my point of view, that's something I'd strongly suggest **not** to do, ever.

Comment: @Littlefoot : We are trying to generate the csv with (pipe) delimiter, If there is a pipe in actual data then CSV will be corrupted if double quotes are not present. That is why double quotes are used.

Comment: Aha. That makes sense, and that's something I didn't think about. Thank you for explaining it. Perhaps you'd want to add it to your answer, to avoid confusion. If it confused me, I guess it'll confuse someone else too.